# Is SynchronizationContext.Post() threadsafe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization, locking

This is a pretty basic question, and I imagine that it is, but I can't find any definitive answer. Is `SynchronizationContext.Post()` threadsafe?

I have a member variable which holds the main thread's context, and `_context.Post()` is being called from multiple threads. I imagine that `Post()` could be called simultaneously on the object. Should I do something like

```
lock (_contextLock) _context.Post(myDelegate, myEventArgs);
```

or is that unnecessary?

**Edit:**
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) states that "*Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.*" Should I keep my `lock()`, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going strictly off the MSDN documentation then no, the `SynchronizationContext.Post` method is not thread-safe. So unless there is an error in the documentation then you will need to synchronize access to the method. I find hard to believe that it is not thread-safe myself, but you cannot bank on assumptions especially when dealing with thread synchronization issues. There really is no way around this until Microsoft either corrects the documentation or truly makes it thread-safe.

Comment: Looking at the disassembled code this method just calls ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem which, according to msdn, IS thread safe.

Comment: @Phil: That is not surprising. Unfortunately Microsoft has effectively reserved the right to change the implementation in a way that would void its current thread-safe behavior in a future release or service pack. My guess is that they really did intend for that class to have thread-safe instance methods and that they just screwed up the documentation.  But, again, that is just an assumption.

Comment: Given its usage it would be silly for them to change it to not be thread safe!

Comment: @RichardOD: I totally agree! They really need to fix the documentation. And this isn't the only instance needing to be fixed either.

Answer (score 2):

`SynchronizationContext.Post` is threadsafe. The documentation has overlooked this fact.

I base this assertion on Microsoft's implementations of `AsyncOperation` and `AsyncOperationManager`, which assume `SynchronizationContext.Post` is threadsafe (including any derived implementations).